# AR Foundation - TrackedPoseDriver component being not cached in update loop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The snippet below is quoted from ARSessionOrigin.cs in ARFoundation package 2.0.0-preview.22

```
#if !UNITY_WEBGL
        Pose GetCameraOriginPose()
        {
            var trackedPoseDriver = camera.GetComponent<TrackedPoseDriver>();
            if (trackedPoseDriver != null)
            {
                var localOriginPose = trackedPoseDriver.originPose;
                var parent = camera.transform.parent;

                if (parent == null)
                    return localOriginPose;

                return parent.TransformPose(localOriginPose);
            }

            return Pose.identity;
        }

        void Update()
        {
            if (camera != null)
            {
                // Make sure the trackables has the same local transform as the camera's origin
                var pose = GetCameraOriginPose();
                trackablesParent.position = pose.position;
                trackablesParent.rotation = pose.rotation;
            }
        }
#endif
```

Apparently `GetComponent` is called per update loop to update camera pose.
Why not caching the component as field value?
Would be great if someone let me know the exact reason.

Answer (score 0):

Cache the component by adding a private field and reference the value in the Awake or Start method, it makes no sense for me to reference so many times the same component.

```
private TrackedPoseDriver _trackedPoseDriver;

private void Start()
{
    _trackedPoseDriver = camera.GetComponent<TrackedPoseDriver>();
}
```